# Why is not feComponentTransfer using sRGB colour space?

Tags: css, svg, svg-filters, color-space

I have created a filter using `feComponentTransfer`. Even though `sRGB` is passed to `color-interpolation-filters` the output is not the correct one. What could be the issue?

```html
<div>
The following color should have been <code>#378a62 RGB(55,138,98)</code> But it is not.
</div>
<br/>
<img id="something1" src="https://www.ledr.com/colours/white.jpg" />

<svg style="position: absolute; left: -9999em; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 0px;">
  <filter id="filter_duotone">
        <feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" result="duotone">
          <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0 0.21568627451"></feFuncR>
          <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0 0.54117647058"></feFuncG>
          <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0 0.38431372549"></feFuncB>
          <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 1"></feFuncA>
        </feComponentTransfer>
  </filter>
</svg>
```

This is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/acsreedharreddy/9vybm1nt/10/). This does not give the correct output on chrome, but then works on SAFARI and FireFox.

Comment: Presumably a Chrome bug then. Report it to Chrome's bugtracker unless someone else already has.

Comment: I get the same colour on Chrome and Firefox (on a sRGB screen)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Yes if the screen is in sRGB then chrome uses sRGB colour space, But if it is not then this issue occurs.

Comment: This works correctly for me on Chrome / Windows 10. What kind of display are you using that is not using the sRGB color space?

Comment: I am using a mac